# displayvalue, rowsource and rowsourcetype in foxpro 7

Tags: database, data-binding, datatable, visual-foxpro

I have two tables customer and category, to make things simple I'll keep the structure simple :

```
customer
---------
id            name        categoryid
----------------------------------
1             joe          1
2             john         2


category
---------
categoryid            categoryname        
-----------------------------------
1                       User
2                       Admin
```

I have a form with customer name and some other info as text fields, and a combobox in which i would like to display the corresponding categoryname from category table.
knowing that i would like the customer table to always store the categoryid, how can i do this with foxpro databinding ? display the category name value, from category table, and store category id in customer table ?

Answer (score 0):

In the form designer, combo box properties, set the RowSourceType = 2(Alias) and RowSource = "CateGory.Categoryname, CateGory.CategoryId", ControlSource = "Customer.Id", BoundColumn = 2

Also, you will want to add the tables to the DataEnvironment of the form.

Comment: i was able to tell by looking at your code that the controlsource should've been "Customer.categoryid". after testing, your code ddidn't work. thanks anyway

Comment: Make the RowSource "CateGory.Categoryname, CategoryId"; that is, no alias for the second field. Also, use RowSourceType 6-Fields. (2 will work, but clarity is good.)

Answer (score 0):

In the data environment add the table which has the category which you want to view in customer form and use the category ID associated with it.
Use a combo box control to link as data source to the customer table field with the category ID, try using the combo box builder by right clicking your mouse while selecting the combo box on the form, after this is done.
Go to combo Lost Focus event and display by code the category name for the selected category in the combo box using something like this:
Getting the category and displaying it in label on form assuming that the category ID is integer:

```
Local iCatID As Integer
iCatID = ThisForm.Combo.Value
Select CategoryTable
Locate for iCatID = CategoryTable.CategID
IF Found()
ThisForm.Label.Caption = "Category " + Transform(CategoryTable.Category, "@T")
ThisForm.Refresh()
Else
Messagebox("Invalid Category !")
Endif
```

Try it out, hope it works for you.